# Docker: node_modules symlink not working for typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, express

I am working on containerization of Express app in TS. But not able to link node_modules installed outside the container. Volume is also mounted for development.But still getting error in editor(vscode) `Cannot find module 'typeorm' or its corresponding type declarations.`, similar for all dependencies.

```
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.8.0-alpine3.13 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY transformPackage.js .

RUN ["node", "transformPackage"]

FROM node:16.8.0-alpine3.13
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package-docker.json package.json
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

RUN npm install --quiet && mv node_modules ../ && ln -sf ../node_modules node_modules

COPY .  .

EXPOSE 3080

ENV NODE_PATH=./dist

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I've one workaround where I can install dependencies locally, and then use those, but need another solution where we should install dependencies only in the container and not the outside.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this (normal Docker) setup where you have a two-stage build, and the first stage compiles or transforms the source code in some way before the second stage runs it, you can't use a bind mount to replace the image code since that will hide the transformed file.  You should be able to delete that `volumes:` block entirely (and use a host Node process for day-to-day development).

Answer (score 0):

Your first code section implies you use docker-compose. Probably the build (of the Dockerfile) is also done there.

The point is that the volume mappings in the docker-compose are not available during build-phase in that same Docker-service.

Comment: I'm also creating symlink from docker-compose command, that's also not working